# csv file visualization program

Tags: c, csv

I would like to write a program that will open a csv file and create its visualization in a txt file.

I mean:

input:
(this is csv file)

```
apple;orange;strawberry
car;warsaw;ansi
```

output in txt file

```
apple|orange|strawberry
car  |warsaw|      ansi
```

**The idea is that the width of the whole column should be adjusted to the longest expression in it**

output in my program

> apple|orange|strawberry
>
> |car|warsaw|ansi
>
> |

**I have too many separators, and they're not in line**

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000

int how_many_delimiter(char array[]);

int main(void)
{

    FILE *f,*f_2;
    int *size_of_column, counter, hmd, min;
    char corrector[] = ";", rows[MAXLINE], *clipboard;
    
   
    f = fopen("ex-5.csv", "r");
    f_2 = fopen("wynik.txt", "w");
    
    fgets(rows, MAXLINE, f);
    hmd = how_many_delimiter(rows);
    size_of_column = (int*)calloc(hmd,sizeof(int));
    min=10;
    
    
    while(fgets(rows, MAXLINE, f))
    {
        
        
        clipboard = strtok(rows, corrector);
        counter=0;
        
        if(strlen(clipboard)>size_of_column[counter])
        {
            size_of_column[counter] = strlen(clipboard);
        }
       
        while(clipboard!=NULL)
        {
             if(strlen(clipboard)>size_of_column[counter])
             {
                 size_of_column[counter] = strlen(clipboard);
             }
            clipboard = strtok(NULL,corrector);
            counter++;
        }

    }
    
    fclose(f);
     f = fopen("ex-5.csv", "r");
    
    
    while(fgets(rows, MAXLINE, f))
       {
           
           clipboard = strtok(rows, corrector);
           counter=0;
          
           while(clipboard!=NULL)
           {
                fprintf(f_2,"%-*s|",size_of_column[counter], clipboard);
               clipboard = strtok(NULL,corrector);
               counter++;
           }

       }
    

    
    fclose(f);
    fclose(f_2);
    
    return 0;
}

int how_many_delimiter(char array[])
{
    int counter, i;
    
    i = 0;
    counter = 1;
    
    while(array[i]!='\n'&& array[i]!=EOF)
    {
        if(array[i]==';') counter++;
        i++;
        
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a question here?

Comment: Read about [minimum field width](https://alvinalexander.com/programming/printf-format-cheat-sheet/) (updated link)  A string with a minimum length  `printf("'%10s'", "Hello");`  `"     Hello"`

Comment: Yeah, I don't know how to write it down in such a way that it makes a nice table .

Comment: So, if i want minimum length from table, i've to do it like this fprintf(f_2,"%'*s|'",size_of_column[counter], clipboard); ?

Answer (score 2):

Steps to do this (using an alternate to the `"%*s", width` method):

- Loop to get length of longest word in all categories
- `int len = strlen(longestWord);`
- Create format string container `char formatStr[80];`
- Populate `formatStr`:  `sprintf(formatStr, "%s%d%s", "%", len+5, "s");`
  `+5` is arbitrary, change as needed for space between columns.
- Use `formatStr` in the `printf()` statements for each word.

So for example the longest word shown in your example is `strawberry`.  My suggestion was to programmatically parse all of the words into buffers, and loop on them, performing `strlen()` on each to determine longest.  Once you've found, in this case, `strawberry`, `len` will be 10, so the format specifier would be `"%15s"` (if you use my recommended `+5`).  But the value `15` will be in an `int` variable by then (say for example `int longest`.   Since inserting it directly into the normal format string: ( `"%longests"` ) will not compile, it will need to be packaged up into a *format string*, `formatStr` as shown in bullets above, and here:

```
sprintf(formatStr, "%s%d%s", "%", longest + 5, "s|");
```

( Will look like:  `"%s15s|"` )

Once this is done, you can use the format string in the printf statements

This then:

```
fprintf(f_2,"%-*s|",size_of_column[counter], clipboard);
```

Becomes:

```
fprintf(f_2,formatStr, clipboard);
```

(either method will work.)

Comment: Don't forget about the `*` format modifiers in `printf()`.  You can pass an `int` to give the size, and left/right justify with negative/positive values.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - Yes, thanks for mentioning that.  My intent was to frame this as an _alternate_ to using the `*` method, but completely left that out of my answer..  I have edited the first sentence.